# How to handle too many ajax requests in gaming Portal

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, web

How to handle the ajax request in gaming portal. Is there any other way to manage real time responses and manipulate data according to it.

Comment: Why not to use https://socket.io/ ?

Comment: angularjs, websockets for example...

Comment: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)